# kube-proxy / status stuck in Init:0/1 (pending state)

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Having a cluster running two nodes, getting the following for one of the two kube-proxy pods :

```
kube-system  kube-proxy-gke-app-...  0/1  Init:0/1  0  4m
```

A describe command more or less tells the same.

Not knowing enough to understand fully what's happening (the whoel cluster works quite fine), I was wondering if such state for one of the pod could have impact, what was the reason and/or the workaround to solve it

This all runs on gke with nginx-ingress-controller through the load balancer

Thx a lot for any help

Comment: Check if you have further details with `kubectl describe po <pod name> -n kube-system`

Comment: It was overall saying "pending". Ended up replacing the node, problem solved obviously